# Error opening Ember Serve

Tags: javascript, node.js, git, ember.js

After installing node.js, npm, git, ember-cli, phantomjs2 on ubuntu, not able to open ember server and getting the following error:

```js
~$ cd my-app
~/my-app$ ember s
module.js:340
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '../internal/baseEach'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:289:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
    at require (module.js:385:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/naveen/my-app/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/lodash/collection/find.js:1:78)
    at Module._compile (module.js:425:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:432:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:313:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
```

Comment: Looks like your nodejs version might be too old. Try `nodejs -v` to check?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This usually happens when your `npm install` process is disrupted. You should `rm -rf node_modules`, `npm cache clean` and then do clean `npm install`. You might also use `npm install --verbose` which would also tell you what went wrong if process exits with error.

Also you can upgrade to latest version of npm using `npm install -g npm`.